# Getting started with Nested View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am at a total loss with what's wrong with how I've setup my nested views. What am I doing wrong???

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: '/',
      template: '<div><h1>Hello World</h1><div ui-view></div></div>',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('main.test', {
      template: '<div><h2>I\'m here!</h2></div>',
      url: '/here'
    });
});
```

What happens is I go to `/` and it shows me "Hello World", and then I go to `/here` and it shows me a blank page. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You need to omit the preceding / in url:

```
.state('main.test', {
  template: '<div><h2>I\'m here!</h2></div>',
  url: 'here'
 });
```

#### debugging

when clicking on this anchor ui-router navigates to this location: `http://localhost:8000//here`

```
 <a ui-sref="main.test">test</a>
```

In your application you can easily check the url of a state

```
app.run(function($state){
   var href = $state.href('main.test');
   console.log(href); # '//here'   
});
```

#### Be sure to set the server to support html5mode

[$location documantation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

> #### Server side
>
> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your
>   application (e.g. index.html)

Comment: Yeah, I have that setup with express by using a catch all `get('*',/*...*/)` as my last route. But even if I turn off html5 mode, this still doesn't work...